# How are passwords to listen in on the magical radio show "Potterwatch" protected?

Tags: harry-potter, books

In *The Deathly Hallows* (chapter 22 of the same name), Harry, Ron and Hermione manage to listen in on the Potterwatch radio show which is being sent from a secret location by anonymous radio hosts. At the end of the show the host (Lee Jordan, going by a nickname) says

> "Keep twiddling those dials: the next password will be 'Mad-Eye'."

Obviously this distribution of an unencoded password to anyone who is listening is not safe practice. Usually I can ignore obvious plot-holes and Deux-ex-machinations, but this was a stretch. I can't think of an explanation for how they could possibly come up with this password distribution method. What exactly are they thinking, how does the scheme work?

Both in- and out-of- universe explanations are welcome!

PS haven't finished reading. No spoilers please!

Comment: I thought that too. You don't know when the next will be, and you can't easily get in again if you missed one. Brute force is the only option.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The password for the current show was "Albus" which, urm, is by my reckoning pretty weak.

Comment: @rand-althor thanks, before I read that answer does it have spoilers?

Comment: I just checked the answers to the older question. No spoilers there from the later DH plot as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BuckThorn yes, but that was an easy one. Ron tried for weeks if not months to break into it without any luck.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Ok, from the answers to the linked post and your comment I am coming up with an argument to let me move on. Perhaps the "passwords" transmitted by radio are keys and the *actual* passwords to listen in are deduced from the keys based on insider knowledge such as holographic decrypting enchantments. Only Ron found the implementation somewhat difficult.

Comment: @BuckThorn Occam's razor simply says JKR is bad at mathematics. :)